# how can datetime-local have min value?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, min, code-behind, datetime-local

i have asp textbox like that:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxExitTime" TextMode="DateTimeLocal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

i want that  all of the dates (and times) will be in the future.

if it was `<input type="dateTime-Local"/>` i would write in the code behind `TextBoxExitTimeAttributes.Add("min", DateTime.Now.ToString());` but with the asp:textbox it doesnt work.

when i press ctrl+shift+i it shows me `min="26/05/2021 17:18:12"` but i still can choose date from the past.

what can i do?

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, the control should be `input type="datetime-local"`, I can see at least one typo you've made there (i.e. `inut`).  Can you verify what is a typo here, and what is not?

Comment: Also, can up update your title to reflect on your actual issue here.  that control has **min** by [HTML Standard Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#local-date-and-time-state-(type=datetime-local)) (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) as well.  However, this question relates to an issue you're observing, and your title should reflect that observation and issue.